# Unable to deregister service(Spring boot app) from consul

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-consul

Unable to deregister the service from Consul.
Basically Consul official page said that it will deregister service automatically but in my case it won't work like said.

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/basics.html

Hi Referring to the consul Life-cycle its says that

To prevent an accumulation of dead nodes (nodes in either failed or left states), Consul will automatically remove dead nodes out of the catalog. This process is called reaping. This is currently done on a configurable interval of 72 hours (changing the reap interval is not recommended due to its consequences during outage situations). Reaping is similar to leaving, causing all associated services to be deregistered.

This is my bootstrap.yml file

```
server:
 port: 8089
spring:
 application:
   name: ***-service
 cloud:
   consul:
     host: consul-ui
     port: 8500
     discovery:
       deregister: true
       instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value}
       enabled: true
       register: true
       health-check-interval: 20s
       prefer-ip-address: true
     config:
       enabled: true
       prefix: configuration
       defaultContext: shared
       format: YAML
       data-key: data
       watch:
         enabled: true
 endpoints:
   shutdown:
     enabled: true
```

In Consul UI after deleting service using purge command, still shows on Consul UI. So meant that it is not been deregister from Consul

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure this on Consul, as your apps seems to not exit gracefully.
Checkout the consul config property `deregister_critical_service_after`:

> In Consul 0.7 and later, checks that are associated with a service may
> also contain an optional `deregister_critical_service_after` field,
> which is a timeout in the same Go time format as `interval` and `ttl`. If
> a check is in the critical state for more than this configured value,
> then its associated service (and all of its associated checks) will
> automatically be deregistered. The minimum timeout is 1 minute, and
> the process that reaps critical services runs every 30 seconds, so it
> may take slightly longer than the configured timeout to trigger the
> deregistration. This should generally be configured with a timeout
> that's much, much longer than any expected recoverable outage for the
> given service.

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is about consul nodes, not service nodes.

How exactly are you terminating the application?

Comment: For that we are using purge command : 
helm delete *service-name* --purge

Bacially which we are doing purge delete on local mc its working fine means it will deregister services but while on our Kubernetes/Consul cluster it won't.